# I have something strange in BIOS [explicit text]

Tags: bios, virus

I have found this in Boot Priority Order in a colleague's computer (https://www.samsung.com/ru/support/model/NP300V5A-S0URU/).

[Photo of BIOS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTXA2.jpg)

I think the virus did it.
I want get advice about it, maybe somebody known how fix it.

Comment: Probably more likely an ex-employee found out how to rename drives in the BIOS and left a little present.

Comment: This is unlikely, she's not an expert.

Comment: Yeah, it's not a virus. [Zero Google hits](https://www.google.com/search?q="fucking%20shit%20windows%2010%20must%20die") and it would be kinda pointless.

Comment: You would be amazed what people who are "not an expert" get up to when they get annoyed at something. They may not know what they did or how they did it but they're certainly proud they made it do whatever it is.

Answer (score 3):

UEFI firmware<sup>1</sup> has a different boot process – instead of having a single bootloader (MBR) per disk, it has a whole partition to store many bootloaders as `*.efi` files. So instead of putting whole disks in the boot order, **each operating system adds its own "boot order" entry** with a custom path to its .efi file – and of course a custom label.

If you check other PCs, they'll also have a custom entry, only it's named "Windows Boot Manager" most of the time. Normally this is added during OS installation.

But in this case, either the OS didn't install correctly... or the PC's owner accidentally *erased* it by "clearing CMOS" and then had to google for two hours about how to add it back<sup>2</sup>, because they too didn't know that UEFI doesn't boot like IBM PC BIOS anymore. (Note that these entries are stored in NVRAM along with other firmware settings, *not* on the disk itself.)

So if you want to change the label of an EFI boot entry, you can do so through Windows itself – it has the '**bcdedit**' tool which manages both its own BOOTMGR entries *and* UEFI boot entries.

- If you run `bcdedit /enum firmware` you'll see the same list as in the photo. The offending item will most likely have the shortcut {bootmgr} as its 'identifier' – but if it doesn't, make sure to copy whatever {very-long-identifier} it has instead.
- Use `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} description "Windows Boot Manager"` to change the title back to what Windows usually sets.
- Or you can delete the entry, then run `bcdboot c:\windows` to re-add it correctly.

Linux also has `efibootmgr` for the same purpose, which might not let you change the label, but it still allows you to delete boot entries and to add them back.

---

<sup>1</sup> Even if you call it "BIOS", it does not work the way IBM PC-style BIOS used to work.

<sup>2</sup> For reference: the easy way to add it back is to use the 'bcdboot' command from a Windows installation USB stick.